# How can I convert a list to numeric

Tags: r

I have a table with character and numeric values.  I used rbind to combine them:

```
Poll.Data = rbind(c("Schwarzenegger", "Republican", 315, 48.6),... etc.
```

Columns 3 and 4 should be numeric, but they default to character.

So far, I haven't been able to change them to numeric.

Tried:

```
Poll.Data[,4] <- as.numeric(Poll.Data[,4])
```

and

```
Poll.Data[,4] <- as.numeric(as.character(Poll.Data[,4]))
```

What else should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating data using rowwise vector. Vector/matrix can hold data of only one type hence, it coerces numeric values to character.

Convert `Poll.Data` to dataframe and then convert the columns to numeric.

```
Poll.Data <- data.frame(Poll.Data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Poll.Data[3:4] <- lapply(Poll.Data[3:4], as.numeric)
```